# Facebook javascript SDK works with one app id but not another

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been working on creating a publish to stream dialog box with the javascript sdk. I couldn't get it to work, so in frustration I tried replacing the app id with the app id of another app I had previously worked on. Somehow this worked perfectly! There is no difference in the code, only the app id changed.

This is the code. What could be the difference between the two app settings that would cause the sdk to work with one id and not the other? In fact, no new facebook application which I create will work with the javascript sdk. Only my original app.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init({ appId: '696969696969', status: true, cookie: true, channelUrl: 'http://example.com/channel.html' });         

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
        {
            console.log(response.session);
        });

        var publish = {
            method     : 'stream.publish',
            message    : '',
            attachment : {
                name        : 'name',
                caption     : 'caption',
                description : 'description',
                href        : 'http://www.fjdjdj.com'
            },
            action_links : [ { text : 'action link', href : 'http://www.cnn.com' } ],
            user_message_prompt  : 'user prompt'
        };

        FB.ui(publish, function(response) { console.log(response); });            
    };        
</script>
```

Comment: Have you added the "Android Key Hash" for the new Facebook App(the app with the App ID that is not working) you created in your Facebook developer account?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's your application settings, most likely the **Site URL**. If this ***does not*** match your domain that you are running the SDK on, it won't work.

A bonus tip, it's a good idea to remove the application from your user's added applications and re-install it!

Comment: The site urls do match. What would removing the application do?

Answer (score 0):

1-make sure both apps have the same settings on facebook dashboard.
2-that is the funny part. make sure that your app id ad key are correct. Did you copy paste them correctly?

Comment: The settings on both apps definitely match. The strange thing is, I created multiple apps, all with the same settings, and none of them worked. Only the original app I created has an app id I can use for the javascript sdk.